# Issue with passing array, rather simple one?

Tags: java, jtable

I have an easy question, here is my code:

```
public TableForResults( Object [] temp, Object [] tk) {

   ListModel lm = new AbstractListModel() {
   String headers[] = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" };
      public int getSize() {
   return headers.length;
    }
      public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return headers[index];
    }
};
}
```

well it is not my code, I found on java2s. Here is question, I need to pass the tk array into the AbstractListModel(). I know it is basic question, but I can't sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend AbstractListModel and create your own class which will have a constructor to accept Object[] and then you can do the behaviour you want to do.

Comment: damn, that's what I thought. Is there any way to pass the array from another class in the place of header array?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the `tk` array by declaring it as `final` in the parameter list of the function. You can then use it just like a normal variable:

```
public TableForResults(Object[] temp, final Object[] tk)
{
    ListModel lm = new AbstractListModel()
    {            
        public int getSize()
        {
            return tk.length;
        }

        public Object getElementAt(int index)
        {
            return tk[index];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: hmm, u cheer me up mate, it somehow works, but the head rows are blank. It is quite strange, because it returns proper length of an array.

Comment: It has been some time since I did something with Swing but you may have to somehow trigger an update in the component before the data is displayed.